# Running and reusing DockerComposeContainer in tests / local env

Tags: docker, junit, docker-compose, spring-test, testcontainers

Situation: My app has a docker-compose.yml file with the containers I need for local development, usually before running the app I run `docker-compose up -d SERVICE_NAME`

Now for the integration test I am using [testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org) and I want to reuse the same service that I am using for my local development. If there are no services running, that's fine, the test passes, but if I have the service running, the test is failing because it can not create another service from compose:

```
@Container
private static final DockerComposeContainer<?> dockerComposeContainer;

static {
    dockerComposeContainer = new DockerComposeContainer<>(new File("docker-compose.yml"))
        .withServices(SERVICE_NAME)
        .withExposedService(SERVICE_NAME, SERVICE_PORT);
    dockerComposeContainer.start();
}
```

Is there a way to check during testing if there is a `SERVICE_NAME` service running to avoid creating the `@Container` and just reusing the 'external'?

Answer (score 0):

`@Container` is a [JUnit extension](https://www.testcontainers.org/quickstart/junit_5_quickstart/) annotation that binds lifecycle of the container to the lifecycle of the tests: static fields behave similarly to starting/stopping in `@Before/AfterAll`, instance fields - similarly to `@Before/AfterEach`.

You can always opt in for not using it and manually controlling the lifecycle by calling `start()/stop()`. And then you can of course implement any checks you require.

For example, you can use something similar to:

```
var containers = DockerClientFactory.instance().client().listContainersCmd().exec();
```

to list the containers.

Having said all that, I'd recommend to migrate the test setup to using GenericContainer instead of relying on the DockerCompose module, similar how it's outlined [here](https://github.com/testcontainers/workshop/blob/master/step-10-migrating-from-docker-compose.md)